# Justifying Assumption in Solution for AMC 10 Question

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math, analytic-geometry

Let $R$ be a unit square region and $n \geq 4$ an integer. A point $X$ in the interior of $R$ is called n-ray partitional if there are $n$ rays emanating from $X$ that divide $R$ into $n$ triangles of equal area. How many points are $100$-ray partitional but not $60$-ray partitional?[(AMC 10A 2011/25)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2011_AMC_12A_Problems/Problem_22)

It, as well as Sols 1 and 2 state that 4 of the rays must intersect the vertices of the square. Sol 3 does not make that assumption. (I understood the rest of the video solution. )

Can anyone justify why this statement is true?

Comment: If there are no rays that intersect a vertex, then that vertex will be part of a quadrilateral, not a triangle. Solution 3 implicitly makes that assumption by assuming that each side forms an integral number of triangles.

Comment: Thanks, Got it. If you write it up as an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no rays that intersect a vertex, then that vertex will be part of a quadrilateral, not a triangle.

Solution 3 implicitly makes that assumption by assuming that each side forms an integral number of triangles